# test store method in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit

I am trying to test the store method in the simplest way possible. I don't necessarily need Mockery, I'm fine with actually adding to the database. I couldn't get Mockery to work anyway.

Now I have this:

```
public function testStore()
{
    $data = ['name' => 'TestClub', 'code' => 'TCL'];
    Input::replace($data);
    $this->route('POST', 'clubs.store', $Input::all());
    $this->assertResponseOk();
}
```

This is my controller method:

```
public function store() {
    $validator = Validator::make($data = Input::all(), Club::$rules);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }
    Club::create($data);
    return redirect(Session::get('backUrl'));
}
```

I get a return code 500, I have no idea why. Can I somehow see the request it's sending?

I am using Laravel 5.0

Comment: You can do `$this->dump()` in the test to print out data about the request/response.

Answer (score 0):

First, never use `Input::all()`. You may not know what's in the form when it's submit, instead use `only`.

However, you also shouldn't be putting validation logic in the Controller if you can help it. Instead, you should make a new `Request` and put your validation rules in the `rules` array. Let's look at that

```
php artisan make:request StoreUserRequest
```

Then inside of this Request, you'll add `return true` to your `authorize` function (or whatever logic you need to identify if the user should be able to make the request), and then your rules to the `rules()` function (to the array within the rules function, to be more specific).

Now add your new `StoreUserRequest` as a dependency to the first argument of the `store()` function.

```
public function store(App\Http\Requests\StoreUserRequest $request)
```

Now use the `$request->only()` method to get your fields back.

```
Club::create($request->only(['field1', 'field2', 'blob1', 'text1']);
```

Furthermore, make sure that any fields you wish to add data to are listed within the `protected $fillable` array in your `Club` model.

```
protected $fillable = ['field1', 'field2', 'blob1', 'text1'];
```

This should do it.

Comment: I see lots of suggestions in your answer, but not how this actually will solve the problem.

Comment: But then how can he test this?